# Display image from outside the web root ( public_html )

Tags: php, html, image

**Background:**

- I have a folder with images called uploads or images located outside the website root. ( outside of public_html )
- I am trying to print the image inside let's say image.php.

---

**Rules for doing it:**

- I am trying to do it without using alias mod_rewrite in .htaccess.
- Without showing a black background and image in the middle ( I don't want it like when browsing `domain.com/image.png`. like the example of the picture I mentioned below.
- Without using another page and pass it as get.

---

**What I tried:**

- I checked many questions, one of them is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270931/displaying-images-from-outside-the-site-root) and another is
  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131562/serving-images-from-outside-of-document-root).
- From following the current questions asked above and other tutorials, I came up with
  this:

  ```
  <?php

  $location = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
  $image    = $location . '/public_html/images/banned.png';

  header('Content-Type:image/png');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($image));
  echo file_get_contents($image);

  ?>

  <img src=" <? echo $image; ?> "/>
  ```

It works fine, and here is an example:

[Gyazo](https://gyazo.com/d1efa88d2f85dd0542622b8779000cbf)

---

However, this is not what I am looking for, or trying to do. Again, I am trying to view it as a normal image src as it will be used for a profile picture or other usages.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem is the content type you are sending, did you try to remove it?

Comment: I tried removing it, but it shows hex code like "�PNG  IHDR" and when I tried bin2hex, the page shows a blank page.

Comment: `�PNG` is a PNG file, and you're using `Content-Type:image/jpeg`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, I changed it to image/png from my file where I coded it but forgot to change it from here, sorry.

Comment: well that makes the question unclear now, as does `$file`, what is the value of it? Unless you meant `$image`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Fixed my mistakes from the post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your image.php to

```
<?php
function image() {
$location = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$image    = $location . '/public_html/images/banned.png';

return base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
}
?>
```

In another file where you want to display that image, let's say test.php:

```
<?php
include("image.php");
?>
<img src='data:image/png;base64,<?= image(); ?>' >
```

Comment: Also works in DOMPdf.  Also works by entering the image() function within the `img` tag, like `<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents($image_location))."' >`...

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
echo file_get_contents($image);
?>

<img src=" <? echo $image; ?> "/>
```

is wrong for a few reasons. First, you cannot mix raw image content with HTML markup that way. Also `src` specifies the URL of the image not the raw content.

You can either move your echo `file_get_contents($image);` and related code to separate file, i.e. `image.php`, then reference it in your `src`, passing image name as argument (i.e. `image.php?img=foo.jpg`) - note that if you do this wrong, you will be open to [directory traversal attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack)). Alternatively you can try to use [rectory traversal attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support)[data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) as `src` argument and pass raw content directly that way.